# UIImageView frame origin after applying CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have an UIImageView that I am moving around a circle with CGAffineTransformRotate. Works great! But when the user press a stop bottom I would like to the the actual x- / y- position of the UIImageView. So far I am always getting the original x- / y- values from when the UIImageView was created.

Is there a way to get the actual position, when the user stopped the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and share it in case someone is running a similar case:

From UIBezierPath I use the bounds information and this give me the position where the UIImageView stopped. Here the code:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(iMiddleX, iMiddleY) radius:flR startAngle:degreesToRadians(flDegrees-0.01) endAngle:degreesToRadians(flDegrees) clockwise:YES];

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pathAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
pathAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
pathAnimation.duration = 1.0;

pathAnimation.path = path.CGPath;

NSInteger iX = path.bounds.origin.x;
NSInteger iY = path.bounds.origin.y;
```